# DirectShow GUID missing for DVR device

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, guid, video-capture, directshow.net

I am using DShowNET in a C# project and I have been trying multiple cards. The Card I am trying to access is a GV-800_4A, which is a a capture card normally used by GeoVision CCTV software.

The problem is it is recognized in the device manager as a 'DVR Device' with a different guid than the normal video input devices I have been using **and I do NOT know the DShowNET guid, but believe it may relate to this guid.**

My question is 'How do I convert the **'Device class guid'** seen in devices properties the windows device manager to the Guid used in DirectShow? or are these even equatable?'

**GUIDs in device manager**

- GeoVision GV-800A {4d36e96c-e325-11ce-bfc1-0123456789ab}
- **AVerMedia**  **{4d36e96c-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}**
- **Dazzle USB**  **{4d36e96c-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}**

**GUID in DShowLib**

- VideoInputDevice (0x860BB310, 0x5D01,
  0x11d0, 0xBD, 0x3B, 0x00, 0xA0, 0xC9,
  0x11, 0xCE, 0x86)

**EDIT**

Basically the end goal is to be able to connect this as a capture filter to a graph to save FilterCatergory.VideoInputDevice, but now this device *(GeoVision)* does NOT appear on the list of available capture devices, but it IS a capture device just the drivers recognize it as a 'DVR Device'

I use the CLSID by passing it into the DShowNET function for returning an ArrayList of available devices of that type :

`DsDev.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice, out m_capDevices)`

I need to know the CLSID_[** *DVR Device* **] or where to get that. I thought it could be derived from the 'Device class guid', but I am getting told this is not possible.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the Guid in directshow.net? That would help us figure out which Guid you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
    const string CAPTURE = "•GeoVision GV-800A";
    s_CaptureDevices = BuildDeviceList(FilterCategory.AMKSCapture, CAPTURE);

    private static List<DsDevice> BuildDeviceList(Guid category, string name)
    {
        var list = new List<DsDevice>();
        DsDevice[] devices = DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(category);
        for (int i = 0; i < devices.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(devices[i].Name) && devices[i].Name.Equals(name))
            {
                list.Add(devices[i]);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Another option would be use [GraphEditPlus](http://www.infognition.com/GraphEditPlus/) and add the capture filter to a graph. You can then find out the GUID to create the filter object directly using code like this:

```
var captureFilter = (IBaseFilter) Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new DsGuid("...guid...")));
```